# Histogram matching for arbitrary NumPy arrays

Tags: numpy, scipy

Let's say I have a list of ndarrays A_1, ..., A_n and a special reference array B. I would like to match the histograms of A_1, ..., A_n to the one of B using NumPy/SciPy. Importantly, the arrays are *not* confined to a specific range such as (0-255). All arrays expose a dynamic range of floating point numbers.

My idea would be to normalize both A_1, ..., A_n and B to a fixed range (say 0 to 1). Then I would continue by subdividing the intervals into a fixed number of bins (say 100). However, I fail to see how I can continue from there.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "match"? Do you want the bins chosen for B data and then applied to A data?